# Where would we find a Brazilian claim from German geologist Eschwege?

Tags: reference-request, international-trade, history-economic-thought, marxism

In *Das Kapital*, ch I.1, Marx says that German geologist Eschwege claims that

> total product of the Brazilian diamond mines for the eighty years
> ending in 1823 still did not amount to the price of 1 1/2 years’
> average product of the sugar and coffee plantations of the same
> country,

Where does Eschwege claim that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page 833 of the Grundrisse, Marx cites an indirect source for this quote:

"H.A.M. Merivale, Letures on Colonisation. London 1841, Vol 1, p 52n"

Comment: Fine answer! I found the cite in page 752 in this edition, https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/download/pdf/grundrisse.pdf